# create an array from different objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, socket.io

I've sent data from server side with socket.io :

```
for (i = 0; i<rows.length; i++) {
socket.emit('Switch', {eqid:rows[i].EquipmentID,eqroom:rows[i].Name}); 
}
```

and in the client side :

```
socket.on('Switch', function (data) {
console.log(data.eqid);
 }
```

and what I get is :[console log](http://fr.tinypic.com/r/2ue060o/8)  and when I do `console.log(data.eqid[0]` I get undefined

so I want to get an array `[120336,120337..]`

I've tried also to send an array from the beginning in the server side :

```
for (i = 0; i<rows.length; i++) {
var test=[];
test.push(rows[i].EquipmentID);     
}
console.log(test);
```

console.log gives me the last equipmentID only [120339

Comment: place test=[] outside for loop...

Answer (score 0):

> console.log gives me the last equipmentID only [120339

Because you are redefining `rows` array in every iteration.

Try this:

```
var ids = [];
var names = [];

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    ids.push(rows[i].EquipmentID);   
    names.push(rows[i].Name);  
}

socket.emit('Switch', {eqid: ids, eqroom: names});
```